# Unresolved dependency generating jar with SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I'm developing a Spark process in Scala (Eclipse IDE) and runs fine in my local cluster, but when I try to compiled it with SBT that I installed on my pc I got a error (see picture).

My first doubt is why SBT try to compile with scala 2.12 if I explicitly set scalaVersion to 2.11.11 in my build.sbt. I tried installing other SBT versions with the same results, also in other PCs but not works. I need help to fix it.

- scala_version(Spark) :2.11.11
- sbt_version : 1.0.2
- spark: 2.2

**build.sbt**

```
name := "Comple"
version := "1.0"
organization := "com.antonio.spark"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
)
```

**assembly.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "1.0.2")
```

Error:

```
ResolveException: unresolved dependency: sbt_assembly;1.0.2: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your assembly.sbt file to:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
```

as stated in the documentation here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

I recently used that with spark-core_2.11 version 2.2.0 and it worked.